# AWS credentials cannot be read

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Yesterday the credentials were working fine. Last night I restarted apache (the only thing I can think of that might be the cause). Today I am getting this error:

> Cannot read credentials from /root/.aws/credentials in vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php

The PHP code I'm using is

```
$s3Client = $s3Client ?? S3Client::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'my_profile',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => '2006-03-01'
));
```

and my `.aws/credentials` file looks like

```
[my_profile]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = KEY
```

where `KEY_ID` and `KEY` are their real values in my actual file.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: File permissions or apache user changed?

Comment: @sef4eg I didn't change `credentials` file permissions or the apache user, although I have cycled through possibilities trying to get it to work today.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS credential class seems kinda picky about having a 'HOME' environment variable. Here are some functions to help resolve the path to the credentials file and set the 'HOME' environment variable accordingly.

```
    /**
     * determine path to credentials file
     * @return string
     * */
    protected function _getCredentialsPath(){
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#credential-profiles
        $credentials_path = '';
        $current_user = get_current_user();
        $credentials_file = '.aws/credentials';
        $possible_paths = array( '/Users/%s/%s', '/home/%s/%s' );
        forEach( $possible_paths AS $check_path ){
            $check_credentials_path = sprintf( $check_path, $current_user, $credentials_file );
            if( file_exists( $check_credentials_path ) ){
                $credentials_path = realpath( $check_credentials_path );
                break;
            }
        }
        // set the HOME environment variable if missing
        if( empty( getenv( 'HOME' ) ) && ! empty( $credentials_path ) ){
            $directory = pathinfo( $credentials_path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME );
            $exploded_path = explode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $directory );
            array_pop( $exploded_path ); // remove .aws directory from end
            $home_path = implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $exploded_path );
            putenv( "HOME={$home_path}" );
        }
        return $credentials_path;
    }

    /**
     * get the aws sqs client
     * @return \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient
     * */
    protected function _getAwsSqsClient(){
        if( empty( $this->_aws_sqs_client ) ){
            // SDK Version 3 Syntax
            $credential_profile = $this->_aws_sqs_profile;
            $credential_path = $this->_getCredentialsPath();
            $credential_provider = CredentialProvider::ini( $credential_profile, $credential_path );
            $credential_provider = CredentialProvider::memoize( $credential_provider );
            // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sqs-2012-11-05.html
            $sdk = new \Aws\Sdk(
                array(
                    'region'      => $this->_aws_region,
                    'version'     => $this->_aws_sdk_version,
                    'profile'     => $this->_aws_sqs_profile,
                    'credentials' => $credential_provider,
                )
            );
            $sqs_client = $sdk->createSqs();
            $this->_aws_sqs_client = $sqs_client;
            try{
                $response = $sqs_client->getQueueUrl( array( 'QueueName' => self::AMAZON_SQS_QUEUE_NAME ) );
            }
            catch( \Exception $e ){
                echo "home: ",getenv('HOME'),"<br />";
                echo "credential profile: ",$credential_profile,"<br />";
                echo "credential path: ",$credential_path,"<br />";
                echo "<pre style='color:purple'>credential provider: "; var_dump( $credential_provider ); echo "</pre>\n<br />";
                $file_handle = fopen( $credential_path, 'r' );
                echo "credential content: <pre style='color:blue;'>",fread( $file_handle, filesize( $credential_path ) ),"</pre>\n<br />";
                echo "<pre style='color:red;'>"; var_dump( $e->getMessage() ); echo "</pre>\n";
                die(__FILE__.__LINE__);
            }
            $this->_aws_queue_url = $response->QueueUrl;
        }
        return $this->_aws_sqs_client;
    }
```

Comment: I don't remember how I ended up solving this, but thanks for the functions. If  I'm somewhere and run into the issue again I'll be sure to give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this was your issue, but I had a similar problem and it turned out to be that the ".ini style" credential file (generated by `aws configure`) expected by some apps in `AWS_CONFIG_FILE`, but it's incompatible with the AWS CLI apps such as `ec2-describe-instances` though, which expect `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` to point to a file with a slightly different format:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=...
AWSSecretKey=...
AWSRegion=...
```